# how to solve error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol for imwrite() function?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, opencv3.0

I installed (extracted) opencv at c:/../Opencv 3.0 and ms visual studio 2012. I use cmake for create library. Path for build binary in cmake -> c:/opencv/build custom/ , which different from opencv path. I choose visual studio 11 2012 in cmake.
Also set environment path.
in property manager I set c/c++ > general > AdditionalIncludeDirectories :
 C:\lazy\opencv\build\include;%
Linker > general > AdditionalLibraryDirectories :  C:\opencv\build_custom\lib\Debug;%

Linker > input > AdditionalDependencies : opencv_calib3d300d.lib;opencv_core300d.lib;opencv_features2d300d.lib;opencv_flann300d.lib;opencv_highgui300d.lib;opencv_imgproc300d.lib;opencv_ml300d.lib;opencv_objdetect300d.lib;opencv_photo300d.lib;opencv_stitching300d.lib;opencv_superres300d.lib;opencv_ts300d.lib;opencv_video300d.lib;opencv_videostab300d.lib;

I use below code for svm in ms visual studio:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
//#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
//#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv\cvaux.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#include <opencv2\ml.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Data for visual representation
    int width = 512, height = 512;
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);


    // Set up training data
    int labels[4] = { 1, -1, -1, -1 };
    Mat labelsMat(4, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

    float trainingData[4][2] = { { 501, 10 }, { 255, 10 }, { 501, 255 }, { 10, 501 } };
    Mat trainingDataMat(4, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

    // Set up SVM's parameters

    Ptr<ml::SVM> svm = ml::SVM::create();
    // edit: the params struct got removed,
    // we use setter/getter now:
    svm->setType(ml::SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(ml::SVM::LINEAR);
    svm->setGamma(3);

    svm->train(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);

    Mat res;   // output

    Vec3b green(0, 255, 0), blue(255, 0, 0);
    // Show the decision regions given by the SVM
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {
        Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1, 2) << j, i);
        float response = svm->predict(sampleMat, res);

        if (response == 1)
            image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = green;
        else if (response == -1)
            image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = blue;
        }


    // Show the training data
    int thickness = -1;
    int lineType = 8;
    circle(image, Point(501, 10), 5, Scalar(0, 0, 0), thickness, lineType);
    circle(image, Point(255, 10), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
    circle(image, Point(501, 255), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
    circle(image, Point(10, 501), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);

    // Show support vectors
    thickness = 2;
    lineType = 8;
    Mat sv = svm->getSupportVectors();

    for (int i = 0; i < sv.rows; ++i)
    {
        const float* v = sv.ptr<float>(i);
        circle(image, Point((int)v[0], (int)v[1]), 6, Scalar(128, 128, 128), thickness, lineType);
    }

    imwrite("result.png", image);        // save the image

    imshow("SVM Simple Example", image); // show it to the user
    waitKey(0);

}
```

While debugging I got error.
  This is error, which I got while running programme

How to solve it?

Comment: Look at all the other questions for LNK2019 and opencv: likely your are mixing different configurations and/or platforms. Practically: if opencv was built for, for example, Debug/Win32, your project should use that as well. So no Release/x64 or so.. Also make sure all required libraries were added.

Comment: I use 32 bit pc and also debug/win32 mode. If possible give me link to reconfigure opencv .

Comment: Wow, I honestly did not expect that in OpenCV you have to use debug libraries if you want to compile your code in debug mode, because normally when I don't need the libs' debug infos I just keep them in release mode and it's no problem, and in case of Windows libraries you have no choice but to use release libraries anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The `imwrite` function is in `opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib`, add it to AdditionalDependencies